# I am having problem to train Convolutional Autoencoder by Scene15 dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am having problem to train CAE with scene dataset scene15 which contains 15 categories. I designed CAE and trained, but the loss is over 50% all the time. I am in trouble. Could anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: "but the loss is over 50% all the time" ==> what loss function are you using?

Comment: I used sgd with learning rate 0.1. 1320 Training images n 120 testing images. Do you want to see code? thanks

Comment: I am wondering though what loss function you use because 50% loss sounds confusing

Comment: autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy'). Intially I used sgd as an optimizer and binary_crossentropy. Now, I am doing adadelta with binary_crossentropy. The result seems similar. The reconstruction loss descreases from 69% to 56% for both training and validation set. I used 1320 training images and 120 validation images. I run it for 50 epochs where most of the time it stands at 56% loss.

Comment: ok, but how do you get from cross entropy to percent? The cross entropy for each pixel is $-p \cdot \log(q)$. If both pixels are 0.1, then you have a loss of $0.23$. If both pixels are 0.9, you have a loss of $0.09$. I am not sure if you are averaging or summing the cross entropy for each pixel, but if all pixels are 0.1, even if the reconstruction is correct for each pixel, but in the input image and output images all pixels are 0.1, for 28x28 images, you get a loss of 180. So what does the percent mean in your case?

Comment: I used keras cross entropy. The it is 0.56 most of the time.  I am sorry, I misunderstood. The validation loss and training loss is showing like 0.5666 type.

Comment: for binary cross-entropy as a pixel-wise loss it's still hard to tell though what's good and what's not good. So, it's unclear whether 0.56 is good. In order to find out what the best possible value is (due to the reason mentioned above), you could run the original vs original images and compute the cross entropy. That will give you some idea. If you want a more intuitive interpretation, you would need to use MSE, where 0 always means that there is no difference (i.e., perfect reconstruction)